# Subsonic DAL code generation

Tags: subsonic

I'm trying to generate dal from subsonic. But after generating when I'm trying to compile its giving me an error of multiple definitions with identical signatures. This is my app.config. I'm using subsonic 2.0.

```
<configSections>
 <section name="SubSonicService" 
          type="SubSonic.SubSonicSection, SubSonic" />
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="Hercules" 
      connectionString="Data Source=SOUVIKT\SQLEXPRESS; Database=ERPVIPULDEMO; Integrated Security=true;"/>
</connectionStrings>
<SubSonicService defaultProvider="Hercules">
<providers>
<clear/>
<add name="Hercules" 
     type="SubSonic.SqlDataProvider, SubSonic" 
     connectionStringName="Hercules" 
     generatedNamespace="Hercules"
     fixPluralClassName="false"
     removeUnderscores="false"
     relatedTableLoadPrefix="Get"
     excludeTableList="batchstock" />
</providers>
</SubSonicService>
```

Comment: I tried but still its giving errors.

Comment: Please post the error messages.

Comment: I saw the code and subsonic is generating same function signature and public properties twice or sometimes thrice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're not also using the build provider (in App_Code)